# How do I append a string/number to a string ?

Tags: objective-c, string, append

I have a function

```
 -(void) generateLevelFromPlist:(int)currentLevel{
    NSString *mainPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    itemPositionPlistLocation = [mainPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"levelconfig.plist"];
    NSDictionary * itemPositions = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:itemPositionPlistLocation];
    NSNumber *xVal = [[[[itemPositions objectForKey:@"level + STRING/NUMBER"]objectForKey:@"hexposition"]objectForKey:@"hexagon1"]objectForKey:@"xVal"];
    int generatedXVal = [xVal integerValue];
    NSLog(@"%d", generatedXVal);
    NSLog(@"%@", itemPositionPlistLocation);



    }
```

where I want to add the variable currentLevel to the string "level" as in `objectForKey:@"level + STRING/NUMBER"`

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. The easiest in this case is:

`myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level + %d", currentLevel]`

Or

`myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d", initialString, currentLevel]`

You might also consider using valueForKeyPath: rather than objectForKey over and over. (`[x valueForKeyPath:@"a.b.c"]` is similar to `[[[x objectForKey:@"a"] objectForKey:@"b"] objectForKey:@"c"]`)

Comment: Awesome !!! Thank you soo much ! By the way , what I actually wanted was `myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%d", currentLevel]` without the plus ... :)